Tkinter. More than one tag in textbox
I want to tag some words and highlight, but more than one tag is not created

    def open_txt_md_file(self):
        coincidences = []
        with open(self.path, "r") as f:
            n = 0

            for i in f:
                index = 0
                coincidences.append([])
                for x in i:
                    if index >= len(i): break

                    result = i[index:].find(self.find_text)
                    if result != -1:
                        coincidences[n].append(index + result)
                        index += result + 1

                if len(coincidences[n]) > 0:
                    self.text_1.insert(END, i)
                    for x in coincidences[n]:
                        start = "%s.%s" % (n+1, x)
                        end = "%s.%s" % (n+1, len(self.find_text)+1)
                       
                        self.text_1.tag_add("find %s" % start, start, end)
                        self.text_1.tag_config("find %s" % start, background="#00D8EB")
            
                n += 1 


I tried creating tags with different names. I checked with the tag_names function and they were created, but not displayed

better create minimal working code with example data in code - so we could simply copy and test it.

it seems all your tags use the same background="#00D8EB" - so maybe you create objects which already have this background and you can't see it.

@furas is a word search in the text. It highlights all matches in a special color. I create tags for all matches, but only one is shown

When I cobble together working code, I'm able to have your code generate many tags. Why do you think it's only creating 1 tag? You can see how many tags the text widget has with something like print(self.text_1.tag_names())

Did you print out start and end? I got end < start.  I think end should be "%s.%s" % (n+1, x+len(self.find_text)) instead.  Also the line self.text_1.insert(END, i) should be called before if len(coincidences[n]) > 0:.

@BryanOakley I made such a print. It showed that all tags were created. But I don't see them on the screen

Firstly, end is calculated wrong, it should be:
end = "%s.%s" % (n+1, x+len(self.find_text))

Secondly, the line self.text_1.insert(tk.END, i) should be called before the if len(coincidences[n]) > 0: block.
Below is an simplified example:
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.find_text = "self"
        self.path = __file__

        self.text_1 = tk.Text(self, width=80, height=20)
        self.text_1.pack()

        self.open_txt_md_file()

    def open_txt_md_file(self):
        coincidences = []
        with open(self.path, "r") as f:
            n = 0

            for i in f:
                index = 0
                coincidences.append([])
                for x in i:
                    if index >= len(i): break

                    result = i[index:].find(self.find_text)
                    if result != -1:
                        coincidences[n].append(index + result)
                        index += result + 1

                self.text_1.insert(tk.END, i)
                if len(coincidences[n]) > 0:
                    for x in coincidences[n]:
                        start = "%s.%s" % (n+1, x)
                        end = "%s.%s" % (n+1, x+len(self.find_text))
                        print(f"{start=} {end=}")

                        self.text_1.tag_add("find %s" % start, start, end)
                        self.text_1.tag_config("find %s" % start, background="#00D8EB")

                n += 1

app = App()
app.mainloop()

Result:


Thank you very much! I hadn't noticed such a small mistake and couldn't figure out what the problem was for a long time. Thank you!
